# How to extract triples from two data frames in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames like this, which I extracted from a large corpus of documents:

```
id <- c("doc7")
lemma_target <- c("Teilestatus", "Meldung", "Datum", "Datum", "Betriebsarten")
lemma <- c("ergeben", "senden", "ermitteln", "sammeln", "enthalten")
origin <- c("oa_relations")

oa_relations <- data.frame(id, lemma_target, lemma, origin)

id <- c("doc7")
lemma_target <- c("Information", "welch", "teilen", "System", "Datum")
lemma <- c("ergeben", "werden", "werden", "sammeln", "enthalten")
origin <- c("sb_relations")

sb_relations <- data.frame(id, lemma_target, lemma, origin)
```

Now I want to extract triples from the two data frames, in my example `System - sammeln - Datum`: I want all `lemma_target` where `lemma` is the same (in this case "sammeln") from the same document (in this case `doc7`).
I tried to join the dfs using `rbind` and then filter and select but it won't work because I'm getting confused with SQL-syntax... Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just want to merge the data, but it is a little unlucky that you used the exact same variable names in both dataframes. Therefore, the `merge()` function does not work without a little tweak on the data, because otherwise it searches for identical values across all shared variable names . I added `"_oa"` and `"_sb"` to your `"lemma_target"` variable names and assumed that the `origin` variable names are not necessary.

```
colnames(oa_relations)[2] <- "lemma_target_oa"
colnames(sb_relations)[2] <- "lemma_target_sb"
oa_relations$origin <- NULL
sb_relations$origin <- NULL

merge(oa_relations, sb_relations)
```

This gives:

```
    id     lemma lemma_target_oa lemma_target_sb
1 doc7 enthalten   Betriebsarten           Datum
2 doc7   ergeben     Teilestatus     Information
3 doc7   sammeln           Datum          System
```

Comment: Okay, I get your idea - but why would you assign the `origin` column the value NULL?

Comment: By assigning NULL the column gets deleted. I did so because it seems like it is unnecessary.

Comment: The `merge` function was exactly what I was looking for! Having extracted the example from a larger df, I did not consider that duplicate variables would be a problem - I will change it in my data.